# How to make some constraint to be evaluated first in mysql?

Tags: optimization, mysql

```
SELECT BusinessID
FROM
  tableauxiliary
WHERE
  MBRContains(
        GeomFromText (
            'MULTIPOINT(-6.1928749092968 106.7651250907,-6.1771250907032 106.7808749093)'
            ),
            Latlong)    
  AND MATCH (FullTextSearch) AGAINST ('res*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AND Prominent >15
```

I want MBRContains restriction to be executed first because it's far more restrictive. But mysql optimizer uses the FullTextSearch first.

I ended up using subquery to force MBRContains to be executed first. I want easier way.